# magento2: table rates csv file with ISO-3166-2-Code shows issue

Tags: magento2, import, csv, table-rates

[image]

In the column "Region/State" im using  ISO-3166-2-Codes for Germany (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:DE) , but Magento is showing me this Message:

[image]

How can I solve this ?

-
Update:

In the db table `directory_country_region` we can see country codes and region/state codes of every country. The value of "Region/State" (of tablerates.csv) must be in the same format as in that table. The table content can be seen via phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wrong region code.

Replace region code with

> HAM

I hope now it will work for you.